# Fragment UI not getting displayed

Tags: android

Activity Layout : activity_text_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FrameLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer_TextEntry"
           />
```

Fragment Layout : fragment_text_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/Text_Entry_Date"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/choose_date_text"
     android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

     />
 <requestFocus />

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/Text_Entry_Title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/choose_title_text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >


     </EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Text_Entry_Content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="100"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:hint="@string/enter_text_here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >


</EditText>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Text_Entry_Button_Save"
        android:text="@string/action_Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Text_Entry_Button_Cancel"
        android:text="@string/action_Cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity : TextEntryActivity

```
package com.app.journal_v001;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TextEntryActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_entry);



        FragmentManager m_fm_text_entry_activity = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Fragment m_f_text_entry_activity = m_fm_text_entry_activity.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer_TextEntry);

        if(m_f_text_entry_activity == null)
        {

            m_f_text_entry_activity = new Fragment();

            m_fm_text_entry_activity.beginTransaction()
                                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer_TextEntry, m_f_text_entry_activity)
                                    .commit();


        }
    }

}
```

Fragment : TextEntryFragment

```
package com.app.journal_v001;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TextEntryFragment extends Fragment {

//private Button m_btn_Text_Entry_Save;
//private Button m_btn_Text_Entry_Cancel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflate,ViewGroup parent,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_entry, parent, false);
        return v;
}

}
```

I am trying to render TextEntryFragment(fragment) from this TextEntryActivity(activity).
I have kept a series of toasts in various places to track and I can see my code is getting executed till FragmentManager's FragmentTransaction and after that it does not seem to call the Fragment's onCreate/onCreateView.

Can anyone point me whats wrong ?
When I execute I am not able to see the fragment UI being rendered.

Comment: you never commit a transaction if m_f_text_entry_activity != null. Are you sure at least one time this condtion is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
if(m_f_text_entry_activity == null)
        {

            m_f_text_entry_activity = new Fragment();

            m_fm_text_entry_activity.beginTransaction()
                                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer_TextEntry, m_f_text_entry_activity)
                                    .commit();


        }
```

and replace with

```
m_fm_text_entry_activity.beginTransaction()
                                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer_TextEntry, m_f_text_entry_activity)
                                    .commit();
```

==================EDIT==================================

Also

```
TextEntryFragment m_f_text_entry_activity=new TextEntryFragment();
```

instead of

```
Fragment m_f_text_entry_activity = m_fm_text_entry_activity.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer_TextEntry);
```

Comment: I get NullPointerException when doing what you have suggested

Comment: Also two things a) typo in your object creation statement which i corrected when testing (....new m_f_text_entry_activity()...) b) it is working fine even with Null check statement.I purposely added that Null check because the fragment may be in the backstack of FragmentManager and the actual cause for issue was I was using "=new Fragment" instead of "=new TextEntryFragment"..Thanks though for your help..I upvoted your answer